# Must not run with sudo

Tags: devops, pipeline, digital-ocean, github-actions

Hi I am new in github actions and I am trying to create a CICD pipline using Github action. I am using a digital ocean droplet as my server and I am trying to create a runner as said in github->settings->actions

When I wrote the following command
 `./config.sh --url https://github.com/basobaasnepal/BasobaasWeb --token DFGFSDF234sf3fg45hd`

I got this:
Must not run with sudo

I tried to change the from root user to non root user but didn't work. I also tried `export {AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"}` bur

Answer (score 6):

Are you setting the right variable? I think you can set the `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT` variable to get by this problem using `export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1`, or you can provide it directly to the command:

```
RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1" ./config.sh --url https://github.com/basobaasnepal/BasobaasWeb --token DFGFSDF234sf3fg45hd
```

Comment: Can you give link to the documentation where you found `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT` environmental variable?